# PHP interactive script that calls nano

Tags: shell-script, php, interactive

I have written simple PHP programs meant for the command line that run a script to completion with the hashbang at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php //etc
```

However I need to write a script that

- Tells the user they need to create a file named config.xml if it's not there and give a prompt to `Continue?   Y  N`
- If the file is there, then edit it
- Either way, the program fires off `nano`
- On exit from nano the program continues to execute

It is the interactive part that I have never done before, as well as sending to/exiting from another process (nano).  How do I make a script interactive and then get the result from another program?

Answer (score 1):

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614715/open-vim-from-php-cli

Try with:

```
<?php 
system("vi config.xml > `tty`");
?>
```

And modify it in order to be executed under your prompt options.